# Finding/Handling stalled PHP scripts

Tags: php, ajax, find, scripting, hung

I use Ajax to kick off a PHP script that can take a few hours to run.  It's done asynchronously so the PHP script will complete even if the browser is closed.

I need to handle any of these PHP scripts that have stalled/hung for whatever reason.  What is the best way to go about this?  Is there a way to get a process id for the PHP script that can be used to check for activity periodically?  I need to kill any outstanding scripts before starting a new one.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but launching a script that works for hours from the browser feels wrong : is there no way you could send it from the command-line, maybe using a cron job ?

Comment: I wish I could vote up about 10 times on Pascal MARTIN's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution might be based on this idea :

- At the beginning of the long-running script, use [`getmypid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php) to get its PID (Process Id)
- store that PID in a file
- At the end of the script, just before it ends, delete that file.

When another process is launched, it can check if that file is present :

- if it is and the process with the PID contained in the file is still running, di what you have to :

  - either kill it
  - or stop, considering one process running at the same time is enough
- if the file is present, but the process with that PID is not, it means your first process died (like Fatal Error, for instance)
- if the file is not present, it means the first process finished normally

About detecting whether a process is running, and eventually killing it, I'm not sure if PHP provides that kind of functionnalities... It might be necessary to use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to call command-line utilities like `ps` and `kill`...

Comment: Thanks, very very helpful.  Yes I can run it via exec.  A couple more details: 1) Not all will take hours - some will only take minutes, 2) The restriction is one process per user, not total, and there may be dozens of users at a time or more.

As a followup, is there an effective way for a PHP script to monitor resources so I don't potentially blow up my server?

Comment: If you are on a Linux server, maybe http://php.net/sys_getloadavg could do (depending on what you do) ;; if there are dozens of users and processes at a time, be careful not to "eat" too many Apache processes, as only MaxClients of them can run at the same time.